# Get package name or package build directory inside dpkg-buildpackage (debhelper)

Tags: debian, packaging, debhelper, dpkg-buildpackage

When creating a Debian package with `dpkg-buildpackage` (and `debhelper`), I am using the following entry in `debian/rules` for assigning ownership of `my-config` to `my-user` (instead of `root`):

```
override_dh_fixperms:
        dh_fixperms
        chown my-user:my-user $(CURDIR)/debian/my-package/etc/my-config
```

`dpkg-buildpackage` runs as part of a build pipeline where the package name may be chosen as either `my-package` or `my-package-n` (`n` is an integer). It currently fails in the case of `my-package-n` because of the mismatch to the constant directory name `my-package` in the path for `chown`.

Is there mechanism in `dpkg_buildpackage` (and `debhelper` in particular) that gives access to the package name (`my-package` or `my-package-n` in my case) or the package build directory (`$(CURDIR)/debian/my-package` or `$(CURDIR)/debian/my-package-n` in my case)?

I've printed "ordinary" environment variables with `set` between in `dh_fixperms` and `chown`: apparently none such holds the desired information.

Answer (score 1):

## Approach 1: Introspection

The `debhelper` package includes two `dh_*`-programs that parse the `debhelper` command line arguments (e.g. `-v`/`--verbose`, `-B`/`--builddir`/`--builddirectory`, `-N`/`--no-package`), environment variables (e.g. `DH_VERBOSE`, `DH_OPTIONS`), and package metadata to print them for introspection/use by other scripts/tooling:

1. [`dh_listpackages`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/debhelper/dh_listpackages.1.en.html) lists the binary packages `debhelper` programs would act on:

   ```bash
   $ dh_listpackage
   my-package
   ```
2. [`dh_assistant`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/debhelper/dh_assistant.1.en.html) provides various sub commands, that print information as JSON:

   ```bash
   $ dh_assistant which-build-system
   {
      "build-directory": "obj-x86_64-linux-gnu",
      "build-system": "makefile",
      "buildpath": "obj-x86_64-linux-gnu",
      "dest-directory": null,
      "for-build-step": "configure",
      "parallel": "16",
      "source-directory": ".",
      "upstream-arguments": []
   }
   $ dh_assistant active-compat-level
   {
      "active-compat-level": 13,
      "declared-compat-level": 13,
      "declared-compat-level-source": "Build-Depends: debhelper-compat (= 13)"
   }
   ```

In your particular case, `dh_listpackages` should do the job:

```
PACKAGE := $(shell dh_listpackages)

override_dh_fixperms:
        dh_fixperms
        chown my-user:my-user $(CURDIR)/debian/$(PACKAGE)/etc/my-config
```

Please keep in mind, that `dh_listpackages` will return multiple packages, if your source package produces multiple binary packages.

## Approach 2: Well-known binary package directory

You appear to have a source package that produces a single binary package (with a varying name) with a compatibility less than `15`.  Until compatibility level `15`, by default `debian/<package-name>` is used for single binary and `debian/tmp` for multiple binary packages.

[Starting with compatibility `15`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/debhelper/debhelper-compat-upgrade-checklist.7.en.html), `debhelper` will by default always use `debian/tmp` also for single binary packages.

Regardless of the compatibility level, you can force a specific package directory with the `-P`/`--tmpdir` option:

```
%:
    dh $@ --tmpdir=debian/tmp

override_dh_fixperms:
        dh_fixperms
        chown my-user:my-user $(CURDIR)/debian/tmp/etc/my-config
```